# Setting function-scope variable to avoid using a capture list

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following class, which uses a closure in one of its methods:

```
class SomeClass {
    let someOtherClassInstance: OtherClass

    func performAsyncTask() {
         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
              print("\(self?.someOtherClassInstance)")
         }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I can also rewrite `performAsyncTask` as:

```
func performAsyncTask() {
     let instance = self.someOtherClassInstance

     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
          print("\(instance)")
     }
}
```

The main goal is that I can avoid making `self` weak in the capture list - or rather so that I don't have to access `self` at all. There seems to be no reference to `self` in the second version, but is there a possibility that there will be an error when I try to access `instance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine (assuming that `self.someOtherClassInstance` has no
back references to the `SomeClass` instance). You can achieve the
same with a capture list:

```
func performAsyncTask() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        [instance = self.someOtherClassInstance] in
        print("\(instance)")
    }
}
```

The closure captures a strong reference to the 
`OtherClass` instance which is held until it has been executed,
but no reference to `self`.

Note that the closure accesses `instance` regardless of whether
the `SomeClass` instance still exists or not, so the behavior is
slightly different from what your first method does.

Comment: What happens if the `SomeClass` instance gets deallocated and no other object in the application holds a reference to `someOtherClassInstance`? Will it be kept alive until the closure finishes execution unless the capture list is specified as something like `[weak instance = self.someOtherClassInstance]`?

Comment: @peco: Yes, exactly.